# Why dont the Commands sync

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, synchronization, bots

I wanted to make a bot with Command Classes/groups being in their own file like: Overall Talent Pairs ...

However I can't get the commands synced back to the main.py.
I first tried to do it with a individal Cog file but since that didnt work I switched to the following code as this worked fine besides the syncing.

**main.py**

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
import asyncio

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.messages = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)

async def load_extensions():
    for filename in os.listdir("./Modules"):
        if filename.endswith(".py"):
            try:
                await bot.load_extension(f"Modules.{filename[:-3]}")
                print(f"Loaded extension: Modules.{filename[:-3]}")
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Failed to load extension {filename[:-3]}: {e}")

async def main():
    await load_extensions()     

@bot.event
async def on_ready():

    print(f'{bot.user} is now running!')

    try:
        synced = await bot.tree.sync()
        print(f"synced {len(synced)} command(s)")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")



bot.run("token")
asyncio.run(main())
```

**Modules.Overall.py**

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class Overall(commands.Cog, name="Overall"):
    def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.slash_command(name="ping")
    async def ping(self, ctx: commands.Context):
        await ctx.send(f"Pong! Latency: {round(self.bot.latency * 1000)}ms")

    @commands.slash_command(name="credits")
    async def credits(self, ctx: commands.Context):
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Credits", description="Created by [Your Name]")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)

async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(Overall(bot))
```

I think it might be because something is in the wrong order or is read wrong yet I cant find anything like that.
I was already asking some friend that knows more than me, he said it might be because of the directory, yet from what we found it looks fine: [Folder of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J22tb.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is because [`commands.Bot.run`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.run) is blocking. According to the documentation:

> This function must be the last function to call due to the fact that it is blocking. That means that registration of events or anything being called after this function call will not execute until it returns.

So you should call `await main()` somewhere else, for example inside your `on_ready` function.